# Transformation of a group of real values to a list

Tags: python

I am collecting measurements from an equipment in .csv format. Each cell has a group of values separated by comma. Example is given below,

```
cell = 0.0871666666666667,0.0866,0.0862,0.083,0.0834,0.0812857142857143,0.08075,0.0782,0.0751,0.0748181818181818,0.0737142857142857,0.072,0.07,0.07,0.0680833333333333,0.068,0.0654615384615385,0.0641818181818182,0.0616428571428571,0.0615714285714286,0.0599411764705882,0.0587857142857143,0.0573478260869565,0.0554285714285714,0.0545652173913044,0.0523225806451613,0.0511818181818182,0.0492553191489362,0.0480322580645161,
```

Above cell is on `object` format. 
I want to convert this to a list of float values as

```
desired_output = [0.0871666666666667,0.0866,0.0862,0.083,0.0834,0.0812857142857143,0.08075,0.0782,0.0751,0.0748181818181818,0.0737142857142857,0.072,0.07,0.07,0.0680833333333333,0.068,0.0654615384615385,0.0641818181818182,0.0616428571428571,0.0615714285714286,0.0599411764705882,0.0587857142857143,0.0573478260869565,0.0554285714285714,0.0545652173913044,0.0523225806451613,0.0511818181818182,0.0492553191489362,0.0480322580645161]
```

I did the following conversion. But it did not do as I wanted above. My code is given below.

```
actual_output = list(cell)
print(actual_output)
actual_output = ['0', '.', '0', '9', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '9', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', ',', '0', '.', '0', '9', '0', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '7', '1', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '6', '6', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '6', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '3', '4', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '1', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '8', '0', '7', '5', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', '8', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', '5', '1', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', '4', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', '3', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', ',', '0', '.', '0', '7', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '8', '0', '8', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '8', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '5', '4', '6', '1', '5', '3', '8', '4', '6', '1', '5', '3', '8', '5', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '4', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '1', '6', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', ',', '0', '.', '0', '6', '1', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '6', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '9', '9', '4', '1', '1', '7', '6', '4', '7', '0', '5', '8', '8', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '8', '7', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '7', '3', '4', '7', '8', '2', '6', '0', '8', '6', '9', '5', '6', '5', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '5', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', '2', '8', '5', '7', '1', '4', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '4', '5', '6', '5', '2', '1', '7', '3', '9', '1', '3', '0', '4', '4', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '2', '3', '2', '2', '5', '8', '0', '6', '4', '5', '1', '6', '1', '3', ',', '0', '.', '0', '5', '1', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '1', '8', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '4', '9', '2', '5', '5', '3', '1', '9', '1', '4', '8', '9', '3', '6', '2', ',', '0', '.', '0', '4', '8', '0', '3', '2', '2', '5', '8', '0', '6', '4', '5', '1', '6', '1', ',']
```

Any suggestions please.

One of suggested approach:

```
x = 2.809,2.812,2.813,2.808,2.804
print(x)
str_list = x.split(',')
print(str_list)
flt_lst = [float(a) for a in str_list]
print(flt_lst)
```

Output is:

```
x = 2.809,2.812,2.813,2.808,2.804
str_list = ['2.809', '2.812', '2.813', '2.808', '2.804']
string could not be converted to float
```

Comment: not enough information, please provide the complete csv format, because most probably it simply can do with pandas methods as pandas quite good at csv reading, furthermore in the data process and arranging is useful too. But whatever method u use csv structure needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `cell` is a string  so your `list` call is making it an iterable. Try

```
str_lst = cell.split(',')
float_lst = [float(x) for x in str_lst]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough for me to go on. Provide the error, the inputs, etc.